# need some help in compiling a jsoncpp sample code

Tags: jsoncpp

I am trying to compile a sample jsoncpp example, but there are tons of compiling errors showing up in "standard" headers. did any body see this any time ?

```
[~]$ g++ -g -c json.cc -I/usr/local/include/json 
In file included from /usr/include/libio.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/cstdio:45,
                 from json.cc:1:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:46:44: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:50:44: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:135:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:151:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:209:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:218:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:227:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:236:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:248:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:258:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:267:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:275:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:289:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:297:43: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:326:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:338:20: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:343:20: error: missing binary operator before token "("
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:350:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/cstring:45,
                 from json.cc:2:
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it was the features.h included with json-cpp conflicting with the system features.h in some other includes. I renamed it locally to json_features.h in the json-cpp code and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Check JSON include path. In compilation option use `-I/path of JSON include directory`, e.g. `-I$(pkg-config --cflags jsoncpp)`.

Comment: This is the *cause* of the problem: Including from `/usr/include/json`, so that jsoncpp's `value.h` takes precedence over gcc's `value.h`, causes these exact errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include header file using this way: 
#include "json/json.h"

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with `-I.../include/json`, then the standard library might accidentally include a JSON header. (In this case, according to asuter, it was `features.h`.)

The parent directory is a kind of "namespace" for header files. That's why a good practice for *any* library with headers like `incdir/foo/bar.h` is `-Iincdir` and `#include <foo/bar.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the kind of thing that would happen if one of your headers that preceded it had a syntax error such as a missing `;` at end of class declaration.  Start by cleaning those.