# mismatched c++ header versions

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, c++11

I've just installed g++ 4.8 on my ubuntu system in order to meet some prerequisites.  But now I'm seeing some c++ compilation errors like this one:

build command:
g++-4.8 -m64 -std=c++0x   -c -g -I/usr/include/jsoncpp/json -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/803384703/CharNode.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/803384703/CharNode.o ../doublets/CharNode.cpp

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:420:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:59,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60,
             from ../doublets/CharNode.h:13,
             from ../doublets/CharNode.cpp:9:

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
                  ^
```

It seems to be complaining about the parenthesis?

Also, (on other errors) I think there's a version mismatch between wchar.h (c99) and everything else which is c++0x (C11). Any ideas how to get ahold of the c11 standard headers and install them in ubuntu?

Comment: You should show more source code. You may want to `#include <features.h>` and to pass `-Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=c++11` to `g++` (perhaps also `-H`); also which GCC 4.8 have you installed and how (the Ubuntu one is a buggy 4.8.1; upgrade to GCC 4.8.2)?

Comment: Hmm, 4.8.1, where do I get 4.8.2, do I need to compile and build it?

Also, I think I've found the issue.  The features.h referred to in os_defines.h might well be the wrong one (I think it's picking up the one from jsoncpp), which is included in the -l build command.  In order to make it grab the right one I'll move the -l reference to jsoncpp back a directory.

Comment: Yes that was it, fixed.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256476

Comment: I have the same problem (not related to jsoncpp) with gcc 5.4.0 and 6.3.0. So I guess it's not a problem of being up to date.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed.

The problem was in the build command:

```
g++-4.8 -m64 -std=c++0x -c -g -I/usr/include/jsoncpp/json -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/803384703/CharNode.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/803384703/CharNode.o ../doublets/CharNode.cpp
```

The `-I` command includes directories to search when locating header files.  Both `os_defines.h` and my own files include reference to different header files with the same name: `features.h`. I think there's a standard one and there's one in the jsoncpp library that I was using.

The problem was that the `-I` command above went one directory too far and should not have had the `/json` on the end.  The standard libraries refer to this file as `features.h`, and internally jsoncpp does the same for its own `features.h` file.

Had I looked down the thousands of generated errors I would have seen that my own references to the jsoncpp libraries header files were resulting in a "header file not found" error, but I didn't get this far.

Comment: I also switched up to -std=c++11 but I haven't upgraded from g++ 4.8.1 to 4.8.2

Comment: this worked for me too. Had to run `make VERBOSE=1 install >& make.log` to catch the culprit g++ command

Comment: Thanks for the save. Jsoncpp here, too.

Comment: Building ROS2 Humble on an older Ubuntu system, same here for `dds/features.h`.